# iOS Swift Live camera preview, get pixel colors

Tags: ios, swift, camera

this is my first question here. I will be so thankful if someone can help me.

I'm trying to apply Black/White filter on iOS camera app and while camera app is working to get percentage of the colors in real time without taking picture.
E.g pointing the camera somewhere and gets white color -  67%, #000 - 23%, #ccc - 10%

Is that even possible? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, filter out a specific color from the image feed?

Comment: Imagine bright color metal door with rust spots on it. The idea is: converted to back&white rust spots will be black color so I want to get what percent of the door is rusted, but without taking picture just place the camera.

Comment: all these technical terms x.x is that the same thing as chroma key? XD

Comment: I think this is what I need. Is it possible and can you give me some examples or something? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: There is something called GPUImage that you can use, it will take some playing around with, but you try looking into that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948886/how-to-apply-chroma-key-filter-with-any-color-to-live-camera-feed-ios

Comment: If you have the time, i would read up on AVFoundation for messing with the camera feed. There are classes like AVCaptureSession that allow you to get the image of the camera and apply a mask to the image feed before displaying it to the user. If this is able to do what you want, i would highly recommend using it over a 3rd party library like GPUImage

Comment: Thanks I will read about it. I also recommend native solution instead of 3rd party

Comment: hi @dneykov , do you have any solution for this issue?
Can you share me, please!